# Как округлить сумму в запросе MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

**Вот что представляет из себя мой запрос к БД и то что выводит**

```
SELECT SUM(shilings) AS total FROM users
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А мне надо чтобы вывело тот же баланс, но без этих десятых или чтобы после точки было хотя бы две цифры.**

Comment: Деньги надо хранить не в DOUBLE, а в DECIMAL.

Answer (score 0):

Используй [ROUND](https://www.w3schools.com/MYSQL/func_mysql_round.asp#:%7E:text=The%20ROUND()%20function%20rounds,()%2C%20and%20TRUNCATE()%20functions.), Люк

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(shilings), 2) AS total FROM users
```

Comment: либо `floor/ceil` для явного округления к целым